# Can't place a control on a form in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm a newbie with Visual Studio Express 2013 and C#.  I've borrowed a simple C# Windows application which builds and runs fine, and now I want to add some objects to the main form.

I select an object from the Toolbox, then click in the Designer on my main form where I want it to appear.  This works fine for some simple objects like Label, but when I select an OpenFileDialog object nothing appears on my form.  An OpenFileDialog "box" appears in a bar below my form instead, and I can't drag it to my form (I get a slashed circle).

I'm surely missing something simple.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need a tutorial for using OpenFileDialog. I hope this will help you http://www.dotnetperls.com/openfiledialog

Comment: Not all controls can be placed into the Form, and this is ok. You don't place the OpenFileDialog on your form because it never shows on the form, instead it offers a complete new functionality, like a new dialog popup window. Some other controls like timers also can't be dropper on the form. But you use those controls like regular once, no need to worry :)

Comment: OpenFileDialog is not a control. It is a component and Component cannot be displayed. So, there is no need to display in winform. That's why the VisualStudio providing panel that contains all component like timer control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot drag an OpenFileDialog to the form because it is a non visual control.
To add an OpenFileDialog,just double click the control in the toolbox.That will add it to the form.Now to show the dialog you have to use OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() in the code behind.Here is an example which shows the dialog on the click of a button.:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
DialogResult result=  openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if(result==DialogResult.OK)
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
{
string s = reader.ReadLine();
}
}
```

Comment: I gave you the answer but it looks like you should do some learning. Why dont you try some books like "head first c#",that will get you to learn the basics .